# Does the ban from review History gets erased when you review for a long time without mistakes?

Tags: discussion, review-queues, review-suspension

I review everyday in stackoverflow. I honestly do make one or two mistakes every month in reviewing. I did observe that each time I make a mistake the time suspension gets longer. Does stackoverflow take in considration the number of time you passed the test? or how longer you did review without making any mistakes? If not does the records get erased by time goes?

Comment: See the second answer, not the first, as the system was changed a little over a year ago.